# Swift 3: How do I increase a variable being displayed as a UILabel, and then update the UILabel programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I have a label that is supposed to display a score, and a button that is supposed to increase that score each time it's pressed. My problem is that I get an error no matter where I put my function.

If I have the function above the viewDidLoad class then I get an error because it comes before my label, but if I put it anywhere inside viewDidLoad I get an error because I can't call a local function, and if I put it anywhere after, then my button calling the function comes before the function.

Where am I supposed to put these things? Is there a better way of doing this all together? This was supposed to be so simple...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let phrase = "Your score: "
var increasingNum = 0

func scoreGoUp (sender: UIButton){

    increasingNum += 1
    label.text = "\(phrase) \(increasingNum)"

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 100, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2 - 10, width: 200, height: 20))
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = "\(phrase) \(increasingNum)"
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 150, y: 100, width: 300, height: 50))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scoreGoUp), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleared up your code. The problem was that, you are not keeping track of you `UILabel`. Just declare a `label` to be visible in the class.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let phrase = "Your score: "
    var increasingNum = 0
    var label: UILabel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 100, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2 - 10, width: 200, height: 20))
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "\(phrase) \(increasingNum)"
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        self.label = label

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 150, y: 100, width: 300, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scoreGoUp), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }

    func scoreGoUp (sender: UIButton){
        increasingNum += 1
        self.label?.text = "\(phrase) \(increasingNum)"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code. Hope this help you.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var label:UILabel!
    let phrase = "Your score: "
    var increasingNum = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 100, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2 - 10, width: 200, height: 20))
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.text = "\(phrase) \(increasingNum)"
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2 - 150, y: 100, width: 300, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scoreGoUp), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(button)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func scoreGoUp (sender: UIButton){

        increasingNum += 1
        label.text = "\(phrase) \(increasingNum)"

    }
}
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afQC2.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your label outside of `viewDidLoad` (like `increasingNum`), at the moment, your `label` variable is only visible inside `viewDidLoad`

```
var label:UILabel!
```